# Sum and Multiply output is wrong

Tags: jquery, sum, calculation, multiplication

I have 4 fields that needs to be summed up which I do with sum up with `$('select :selected').each(function() {` But somehow the below code outputs 99 while it needs to output 72.

```
// Count for ShowerCoins
$(document).ready(function() {
$('select.countForShowerCoins').on('change', function() {
  var sum = 0;

   $('select :selected').each(function() {
       sum += Number($(this).val() * 3) * $('select[name=howManyNights]').val();
   });

$(".result").html(sum);
  });

});
```

The `sum` is "4 input fields with a value of the number 2 each" which is 8 summed up. Then multiplied by 3 and that is 24, then I multiply it with the amount of night's which is 3. 24 * 3 = 72. But somehow I get a output of 99.

Does someone know how this can be, am I missing something? I used `parseInt(` on the `$('select[name=howManyNights]').val();` but that didn't change anything. I noticed that it is because of the `sum` because when I replace that with a static number the calculation works.

But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: It will be great if you can create a jsfiddle/stackblitz of the code.

Comment: Even better: use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) cc @PranavRamachandran

Comment: Note that `$(this).val()` returns a string. You should use `Number($(this).val())`, rather than `Number($(this).val() * 3)`. It doesn't matter either way; what we really need is a [mre] so that we can reproduce the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have an order of operation issue. According to your description you want to `sum` the inputs THEN `x 3 x nights`. Also `$('select[name=howManyNights]')` is a `select`, so it would be included in `$(select :selected).each()` which may be why you're getting an unexpected output.

I'm taking some liberties in guessing what the rest of your code looks like, but hopefully this helps:

```
$('select.countForShowerCoins').on('change', function() {
  let sum = 0

  $('select.countForShowerCoins').each(function() { sum += Number(this.value); })

  $(".result").html(sum * 3 * Number($('select[name="howManyNights"]').val()));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t2jdsk0q/1/
This has the expected output with your given inputs.

Side note: 
`Number($(this).val() * 3)` should be `Number($(this).val()) * 3`.

Fortunately javascript coerces strings to numbers for division/multiplication/subraction, but not for addition.

i.e. `2 * '3' = 6` but `2 + '3' = '23'`

Comment: Yes this works! Thank you for your time. So what i did wrong is using every select, that was stupid of me. I noticed that `sum += Number($(this).val()` is the same as `sum += Number(this.value);` and i noticed when i deleted `Number()` from the `howManyNights.val` it gives the same output. Works either way. And like you said yes. If i didn't use parseInt() i would get `2 + '3' = '23'`. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You are multiplying Nights for every input field and hence the incorrect result. Please try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('select.countForShowerCoins').on('change', function() {
  var sum = 0;

   $('select :selected').each(function() {
       sum += Number($(this).val() * 3);
   });

   if (sum > 0) {
       sum *= $('select[name=howManyNights]').val();
   }

$(".result").html(sum);
  });

});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your time. Output with this is still 99

Comment: Because of i made the mistake to use `$('select :selected').each(function() {` , but further the code looks nice, thank you !